# What is the 'reword' function in Rebol and how do I use it?

Tags: templates, template-engine, rebol, variable-expansion, rebol3

I saw someone mention the `reword` function today, but documentation for it is very brief. It looks like shell script environment variable substitution, or maybe regex substitution, but different. How do I use this function and what kind of gotchas am I going to run into?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Here there be dragons!

The `reword` function is a bit of an experiment to add shell-style string interpolation to Rebol in a way that works with the way we do things. Unlike a lot of Rebol's series functions, it really is optimized for working on just string types, and the design reflects that. The current version is a design prototype, meant to eventually be redone as a native, but it does work as designed so it makes sense to talk about how it works and how to use it.

### What does `reword` do?

Basically this:

```
>> reword "$a is $b." [a "This" b "that"]
== "This is that."
```

It takes a template string, it searches for the escape sequences, and replaces those with the corresponding substitution values. The values are passed to the function as well, as an object, a map, or a block of keys and values. The keys can be pretty much anything, even numbers:

```
>> reword "$1 is $2." [1 "This" 2 "that"]
== "This is that."
```

The keys are converted to strings if they aren't strings already. Keys are considered to be the same if they would be converted to the same string, which is what happens when you do something like this:

```
>> reword "A $a is $a." [a "fox" "a" "brown"]
== "A brown is brown."
```

It's not positional like regex replacement, it's keyword based. If you have a key that is specified more than once in the values block, the last value for that key is the one that gets used, as we just saw. Any unset or none values are just skipped, since those have no meaning when putting stuff into a string.

You can use other escape flags too, even multi-character ones:

```
>> reword/escape "A %%a is %%b." [a "fox" b "brown"] "%%"
== "A fox is brown."
```

Or even have no escape flag at all, and it will replace the key everywhere:

```
>> reword/escape "I am answering you." [I "Brian" am "is" you "Adrian"] none
== "Brian is answerBrianng Adrian."
```

*Whoops, that didn't work.* This is because the keys aren't case-sensitive, and they don't need to be surrounded by spaces or other such delimiters. But, you can put spaces in the keys themselves if you specify them as strings, so this works better:

```
>> reword/escape "I am answering you." ["I am" "Brian is" you "Adrian"] none
== "Brian is answering Adrian."
```

Still, doing `reword` templates without escape characters tends to be tricky and a little bit slower, so it's not done as often.

There's an even better trick though...

### Function replacement

Where `reword` gets really interesting is when you use a function as a replacement value, since that function gets *called* with every rewording. Say, you wanted to replace with a counter:

```
>> reword "$x then $x and $x, also $x" object [y: 1 x: does [++ y]]
== "1 then 2 and 3, also 4"
```

Or maybe even the position, since it can take the string position as a parameter:

```
>> reword "$x then $x and $x, also $x" object [x: func [s] [index? s]]
== "1 then 9 and 16, also 25"
```

*Wait, that doesn't look right, those numbers seem off.* That is because the function is returning the indexes of the *template* string, not the *result* string. Good to keep that in mind when writing these functions. The function doesn't even have to just be assigned to one key, it can detect or use it:

```
>> reword "$x or $y" object [x: y: func [s] [ajoin ["(it's " copy/part s 2 ")"]]]
== "(it's $x) or (it's $y)"
```

See, template variables, escapes and all. And the function can have side effects, like this line counter:

```
>> reword/escape "Hello^/There^/nl" use [x] [x: 0 map reduce ["^/" does [++ x "^/"] "nl" does [x]]] ""
== "Hello^/There^/2"
```

It even comes with the `/into` option, so you can use it to build strings in stages.

But the big gotcha for someone coming from a language with interpolation build in, is...

### Why a values block, why not just use variables like a normal language?

Because *Rebol just doesn't work that way*. Rebol doesn't have lexical binding, it does something else, so in a string there is just no way to know where to get the values of variables from without saying so. In one of those shell languages that has interpolation, it would be the equivalent to having to pass a reference to the environment as a whole to the interpolation function. But hey, we can do just that in Rebol:

```
>> use [x] [x: func [s] [index? s] reword "$x then $x and $x, also $x" bind? 'x]
== "1 then 9 and 16, also 25"
```

That `bind?` method will work in `use`, binding loops and functions. If you are in an object, you can also use `self`:

```
>> o: object [x: func [s] [index? s] y: func [s] [reword s self]]
== make object! [
    x: make function! [[s][index? s]]
    y: make function! [[s][reword s self]]
]
>> o/y "$x then $x and $x, also $x"
== "1 then 9 and 16, also 25"
```

But be careful, or you can end up doing something like this:

```
>> o/y "$x then $x and $x, also $x, finally $y"
** Internal error: stack overflow
```

Dragons! *That's one good reason to keep your variables and your replacement keys separate...*

Comment: Note to self: Add /case and support for a trailing delimiter to `reword`.

Comment: another master-class, above and beyond answer from BrianH.  These are great, we learn about more than what... we learn about how and why too!

Comment: Where do you find reword ? I typed reword in rebolview and it says ** Script Error: reword has no value